# compute accuracy of validation set

Tags: validation, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I saved train and validation set as tfrecord file. Inference gives input images and returns logits. loss and accuracy compute loss and accuracy as well. Using this code network is trained well(train set accuracy increases and loss decreases). But accuracy of validation set is almost fixed. By tensorboard, I found that computing accuracy of validation set create new graph that doesn't use the main graph's weights. How can I predict accuracy on validation set simultaneously?

```
def run_training():
train_images,train_labels = read_and_decode_tfrecord_train(train_data_path)
val_images,val_labels = read_and_decode_tfrecord_validation(validation_data_path)

train_images = tf.cast(train_images,tf.float32)/255.
val_images = tf.cast(train_images,tf.float32)/255.

batch_Xs,batch_Ys=tf.train.shuffle_batch([train_images,train_labels],batch_size=500,capacity=500,min_after_dequeue=100)
batch_xs,batch_ys=tf.train.shuffle_batch([val_images,val_labels],batch_size=500,capacity=500,min_after_dequeue=100)

logits=inference(batch_Xs,1)
total_loss = loss(logits,batch_Ys)
train_op = training(total_loss,learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)
accuracy = evaluation(logits,batch_Ys)

val_logits=inference(batch_xs,1)
val_accuracy = evaluation(val_logits,batch_ys)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), max_to_keep=4,)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

for i in range(NUM_ITER):
    _,loss_value,acc=sess.run([train_op,total_loss,accuracy])
    if i%10==0:
         val_acc,testing_summary_accuracy=sess.run([val_accuracy,testing_summary])
         print 'Iteration:',i, ' Loss:',loss_value,' Train Accuracy:',acc,' Validation Accuracy:',v
```

Comment: and where is the code for inference?

Comment: Do you create two subgraphs (one for each of training and validation) in `inference` function by reusing parameters of the training model for validation model?